# Seeking Advice on Creating Dynamic Forms for a Laravel-based LMS Application

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, laravel, bootstrap-5

I'm currently working on developing an LMS application using Laravel and Bootstrap, and I'm in the process of designing the form for the "Create Course" page. On this page, users should be able to create both the Course Header and Course Content. Each Course Header can have multiple Course Contents, and both should be dynamically addable.

I'm seeking advice and recommendations on what kind of form or third-party tools would be suitable for achieving this dynamic functionality. I've attached a sample image of the "Start Course" page for reference.
[![Sample Image][1]][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EpOs8.jpg

I would appreciate any insights, suggestions, or feedback on how to structure the form effectively and integrate it seamlessly with Laravel and Bootstrap.

Thank you in advance for your valuable input!

I attempted to create a dynamic form for my Laravel-based LMS application using a table structure. The table includes fields for Content Parent, Content Child, and an action button to add videos. Below is a snippet of the HTML structure I used:

````html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>No.</td>
        <td>Content Parent</td>
        <td>Content Child</td>
        <td>Action</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="content_parent_1[]">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="content_child_1[]">
        </td>
        <td>
            <button class="btn btn-lg btn-success">+ Add Video</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<button class="btn btn-lg btn-success">+ Add Course Header</button>```
````